# Как сделать модульный css с помощью webpack, без использования create-react-app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

### Как сделать модульный css с помощью webpack без использования **create-react-app**?

Если создавать React приложение через **create-react-app**, то поддержка модульного css включена сразу

 не нужно ничего шаманить, просто создать файл и импортировать его в компонент:

```
import classes from "./UserInfo.module.css";
```

---

Мой webpack конфиг сейчас выглядит так:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ['babel-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                use: ['style-loader', "css-loader"]
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx']
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
    ],
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './dist',
        hot: true
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/dist',
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    }
};
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Нашел решение без лишних зависимостей: (исходя из ответа andreycrane)** 
css-loader принимает в себя настройки (options), где можно задать `modules: true`.

---

Все правила для создания модульности через пакеты css-loaders и style-loaders:

```
    {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
            'style-loader',
            {
                loader: 'css-loader',
                options: {
                    importLoaders: 1,
                    modules: true
                }
            }
        ],
        include: /\.module\.css$/
    },
    {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
            'style-loader',
            'css-loader'
        ],
        exclude: /\.module\.css$/
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Обратите внимание на этот пакет https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules Он позволяет организовать модульный css в проекте

Comment: Спасибо! В ссылке находился ответ на вопрос о том, что в качестве принимающих параметров есть возможность указать modules: true

Comment: Ваш ответ тоже подходит, но это лишняя зависимость в проект и если есть возможность сделать без доп. пакетов, то лучше воспользуюсь ей :)

Comment: Согласен с обоими замечаниями полностью